# Android: Finger paint with OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, paint, touch-event

I have been searched about how to do a finger draw on screen with OpenGL for 2 days but I cannot find any tutorial. Only Google sample (ApiDemos) fingerPaint but it use canvas. Does anyone have a tutorial about it?
Thanks
Regards

Comment: hey you edited ur question....but i have answered below according to the previous one...

Answer (score 0):

julikorn you haven't searched well on google for this because if you did so you didn't ask this question here.There are lot of tutorial for this on net if let yourself search on net.Below i am posting some links that will help you to solve ur problem.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html

and you will get the bunch of graphics API demos from here...
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/index.html

Comment: Hi himanshu, I don't think FingerPaint using OpenGL. It use a canvas right?

Comment: he asked about a Finger paint application with OpenGL and not using Canvas and android.graphics. If you find a good example @Jutikorn, please let me know, i am searching for this currently.